# $this->fetchRow creates failure in phpunit in Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I followed [Rob Allens ZF 1 Tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/) and wanted to pimp it up with some UnitTesting. But whenever I run the phpunit command, i get the message:

```
here was 1 failure:

1) IndexControllerTest::testDeleteAction
Failed asserting last controller used <"error"> was "Index"

/path/to/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php:1000
/path/to/tests/application/controllers/IndexControllerTest.php:55

FAILURES!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 9, Failures: 1.
```

The Action in question is the deleteAction and looks like this:

```
public function deleteAction() {
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $del = $this->getRequest()->getPost('del');
        if ($del == 'Yes') {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
            $wishes = new Application_Model_DbTable_Wishes();
            $wishes->deleteWish($id);
        }
        $this->_helper->redirector('index');
    }
    else {
        $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
        $wishes = new Application_Model_DbTable_Wishes();
        $this->view->wish = $wishes->getWish($id);
    }
}
```

I tracked the error down to be `$wishes>getWish($id);` so if i go to that function, that looks like this:

```
public function getWish($id) {
    $id = (int) $id;
    $row = $this->fetchRow('id = ' . $id);
    if(!$row){
        throw new Exception("Could not find row $id");
    }
    return $row->toArray();
}
```

it appears the line `$row = $this->fetchRow('id = ' . $id);` causes the problem. And I can't figure out why. All action work just fine, they do as expected.Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the *select()* object instead if a plain string:

```
public function getWish($id) {
    $id = (int) $id;
    $select = $this->select();
    $select->where('id = ?', $id);
    $row = $this->fetchRow($select);
    if(!$row){
        throw new Exception("Could not find row $id");
    }
    return $row->toArray();
}
```

This just a wild guess, but who knows. The only thing that looks at all odd is the lack of a placeholder in the query string *(?)*.

*FetchRow()* does like to work with the *select()* object, in fact if you pass a string the first thing fetchRow() does is build a *select()*. So *maybe* it just doesn't like the string.